# Git is setting assume-unchanged bit on files

Tags: git, windows-7, msysgit

I first experienced this issue in an existing repository. As a test, I made a change to a tracked file. Running `git status` shows the file as modified. Then I did `git reset --hard HEAD` to undo that change since it was the only change I made. Afterwards, running `git ls-files -v | grep '^[[:lower:]]'` shows that file with a lowercase `h` meaning that the assume-unchanged bit is set. I had not set this bit myself previously.

As another test I did the following:

```
/c/Source/git/test
$ echo "123" > a

/c/Source/git/test
$ echo "456" > b

/c/Source/git/test
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Source/git/test/.git/

/c/Source/git/test (master)
$ git add a b

/c/Source/git/test (master)
$ git commit -m "first"
[master (root-commit) c5bfb90] first
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 a
 create mode 100644 b

/c/Source/git/test (master)
$ git ls-files -v
h a
h b

/c/Source/git/test (master)
$
```

I don't understand what is happening. Why does git mark these files as assume unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had `core.ignoreStat` set to true. `git config --global core.ignoreStat false` fixed it. Not sure why I had ignoreStat enabled... I think I enabled it in an attempt to speed up branch name autocomplete. Which, in retrospect, doesn't make any sense.